# How do I get a distance feeling within a three.js sphere?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using a three.js sphere with a texture inside and the camera is in the center of this sphere. Now I would like to make the texture look away much farer than it actually does.

I tried to raise the radius stepwise from 4.000 ( four thousand ) to 180.000 and after making it almost 50 times as big it still looks the same as near as with any radius from 4.000 to somewhat. Camera.far is set to 200.000.

var sphere_geom             =       new THREE.SphereGeometry                    (   180000,   16,   16   );

Comment: What you're asking for is practically impossible with a single camera. No matter how big/small the sphere is, it'll always cover the same angle range from the camera's point of view. Maybe you could add other objects to your scene to give a sense of scale.

Answer (score -2):

Increase camera fov ? And then call camera.updateProjectionMatrix()

Comment: I tried as you supposed but all 3D- objects in the scene became distorted, too, so I cannot use this option. The spehere indeed looked farer away.

Comment: Yeah. I got a -2 for suggesting that. Guess I'll hold off on any further suggestions. Good luck!

Comment: I saw that and was astonished, too.Thanks for suggesting at all.